# Computing the Fourier-Walsh coefficients of an arithmetic circuit

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, polynomials, fourier-analysis, arithmetic-circuits

Given an $f$-fan in arithmetic circuit of depth $d$ over $GF(q)$ (for some prime $q$) and the set of variables $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, what is the state of the art upper bound for calculating the Fourier-Walsh coefficients of the polynomial it represents ?